# RunDll32.exe missing WinXp

Tags: windows, dll, exe

I have looked every where for a download for the .exe, I have tried the fix.reg sloution, I have tried clicking run and expanding the ex_ file into the .exe, but anytime I click something I am met with this error "Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file" It also says I may not have access to the item. I am the only user/admin and this is a fresh install of the Windows XP black edition.
I cant even use CMD. Surely there has to be a fairly simple solution? Right? I have the RunDll32.ex_ I just dont have permission to run anything like CMD to expand it. Can I simply use a .exe from another computer running same OS?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a big problem on the registry or a broken file system.

As you said you could use a rundll32.exe from another computer with the same version of OS. Check the Service Pack installed in your Windows XP and the other computer.

You could try to copy the DLL to a pendrive from the other computer to yours.

If you cannot copy the new DLL you should need to start Windows in Safe Mode (Press F8 before Windows starts and select on the Black menu text window Boot in Safe Mode), because Windows protects all the files in c:\Windows\ and c:\windows\system32

If Safe Mode don't works, next try should be to use a Windows Live CD. Hiren's Boot has a mini Windows XP embedded.

http://www.hirensbootcd.org/

You need to download the ISO, burn It and boot the computer with it. Run the mini Windows XP and when you see the desktop run the Windows Explorer and copy the DLL from the pendrive to your fixed hard disk. Take care because your hard disk should not be the C: (that should be the mini Windows XP partition), look in other drive units for your data.